# auto multiplication text javascript and auto reduction

Tags: javascript

```
<input type="text" id="txt1"  onkeyup="sum();" onkeypress="return hanyaAngka(event);"/>
    <script>
    function hanyaAngka(evt) {
      var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
       if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))

        return false;
      return true;
    }
                      </script>
```

how to automatically mulitiply everytime i press keyboard
so if i input 1 the result is 1000

input 2 the result is 2000 etc

Comment: ...and input "a" becomes "a000" and input "0" becomes "0000"? Or "NaN" and "0"?

Comment: if the user presses a number key, you want to multiply it by 1000, and when the user takes their hand off, you want to take a sum of all those values. Is that correct?

Comment: yes jrook i want to do that so if the user input 265 the result is 265000

Comment: And what should happen after each `keyup` event? Should the sum reset or not?

Comment: no i dont want to sum just for easynes to type so if i want 1000 i just type 1

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic solution.

```js
var sumkeys = 0;

function sum() {
  console.log("The sum is: " + sumkeys);
  sumkeys = 0;
}


function hanyaAngka(evt) {
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
  if (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)
    return 0;
  else {
    return sumkeys += (charCode - 48) * 1000;
  }

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt1" onkeyup="sum();" onkeypress="return hanyaAngka(event);" />
```

Comment: It is not a perfect solution and there are some situations that can lead to error. But if this has helped you solve your problem, please consider accepting it as the answer!